# How to return a nested array on solidity

Tags: solidity

I am trying to return nested array on solidity 
    error massage says

> "browser/HISTORYMultipleStateMach.sol:22:16: TypeError: Index expression cannot be omitted.
>               return myArray[];
>                      ^-------^"
>       "browser/HISTORYMultipleStateMach.sol:22:16: TypeError: Index expression cannot be omitted.
>               return myArray[];
>                      ^-------^"
>       Can someone tell me what is wrong?
>       Thank you
>         enum State{
>           A,
>           B,
>           C
>           }

```
    State[] curState;
    State[][] myArray;

    uint i=0;
    constructor(uint Machines)public{
        for(i=0;i<Machines;i++){
            curState.push(State.A);
            myArray.push(curState);
        }enter code here
    }


    function historyOfStateMachine() public{
        return myArray[];
    }


   function historyOfStateMachine() public{
        return myArray[];
    }
```

Comment: try removing `[]` in `return myArray[];`

Comment: I removed now its saying  "browser/HISTORYMultipleStateMach.sol:22:9: TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.        return myArray;        ^------------^" @PiotrKamoda

Comment: how about save `Machines` in the outer scope (around where you declare `myArray`) and then do `return myArray[Machines]`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Selen! Can you please format your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the full array, you should remove `[]` in `return myArray[];`

Furthermore, it is not yet possible to return [two levels of dynamic arrays](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/frequently-asked-questions.html#is-it-possible-to-return-an-array-of-strings-string-from-a-solidity-function).

As of [version 0.4.19](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.19) of solidity, you could activate experimental support for arbitrarily nested
arrays using the directive `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`. In which case your code would be as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract MyContract {
    enum State{ A, B, C }

    State[] curState;
    State[][] myArray;

    uint i=0;

    constructor(uint Machines)public{
        for(i=0;i<Machines;i++){
            curState.push(State.A);
            myArray.push(curState);
        }
    }

    function historyOfStateMachine() public view returns (State[][]) {
        return myArray;
    }

}
```